# username in `user:pass@example.com` not in $_SERVER

Tags: php, apache, basic-authentication

To start things off, my server is not running PHP in CGI mode. And even if it was I have the proper mod_rewrite stuff setup (this is a Drupal site).

My problem is that when the user/pass are passed via the URL in the form of `http://user:pass@example.com` then they do not show up in any of `$_SERVER`'s values. Not `PHP_AUTH_USER`, not in `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION`, not in `REMOTE_USER`, or anywhere else within that super global.

If the credentials are passed via the browser's HTTP basic auth dialog or directly using the base64 encoded `Authorization: Basic ZXhhbXBsZTpleGFtcGxl` HTTP header then everything works as expected, `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTH_USER'] is filled out and everything is okay. But if the user/pass are passed via the URL then it's a no go.

Any ideas on what could be going on here?

> PHP 5.3.10
>   Apache 2.2.22

Comment: What browser are you using to test? Have you tried others? Chrome [deprecated this syntax](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123150) (Edit: Better link). I believe it was done to prevent url spoofing... `http://www.google.com               :secure@example.com/`

Comment: I have tried using Safari as well as some tools for just sending HTTP requests.

Comment: It's the browser's job to turn those parts of the URL into the appropriate authorization headers. They aren't sent to the server in the URL.

Comment: So if the browser doesn't do it, there's nothing you can do on the server to recover it.

Comment: Re: tools for sending http requests... The browser is responsible for removing the creds from the url and sending them as appropriate. They're not sent to the server as part of the url, so that's not a fair test. As to Safari, I don't have a copy to hand to test with. I know FF used to work (with a `your're about to log into x as y` prompt) but haven't used it in years. In general, however, it's not a good scheme to support for the reasons mentioned. @Bamar beat me to it

Comment: I have tested Safari 7.0.3 (latest as of now) with a different server that just uses Apache to handle HTTP basic authentication and it works fine in the URL.

Comment: Just figured this out, Safari wont send the header unless it receives a `401 Unauthorized`. Proper answer forthcoming.

Comment: @donut Glad you sorted it. Sorry, I just assumed your server was following the appropriate specs so didn't think to question if it actually announced that it needed authentication. Can you include in your answer why your browser even showed an auth dialog as per your Q if it wasn't getting a `401`?

Comment: @Basic because I was inconsistently sending the `401`. It never showed up when I wasn't sending `401`. It wasn't clear to me at the time that embedding the user/pass in the URL was a feature of the browser, not the server.

[My Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23840198/134014) is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Caching of the `401 Unauthorized` response faked me into thinking there was a problem with the authentication code when there wasn't, it was just sending the cached authentication failure response over and over again despite correct credentials. Disabling the caching fixed the problem.

---

For context, this was all for an API. Basically, Drupal was aggressively caching the responses  from the API, including the `401 Unauthorized` response. But I didn't notice that the reason authorization was failing was due to the caching, I saw two separate problems: responses were being improperly cached and authorization wasn't working in some situations.

That was on production, so in my development environment I disabled caching for the API and then started to troubleshoot the authorization problem, not realizing I had already solved it. As a debugging method, I short-circuited the responses so that the API wouldn't actually check the HTTP Basic Auth credentials, it would just spew debug info (`$_SERVER`, mainly). Because the server was no longer sending `401 Unauthorized` when it should, Safari wasn't packaging up the user and pass in the URL as a HTTP Authorization header. But I hadn't realized that yet.

So, Safari was working with user/pass in the URL on a site that uses Apache for handling HTTP Basic Auth but it wasn't working with my PHP API. This made me think that Apache was eating the authentication in the URL and not sending it along. This idea is what spawned this question.

Thanks to [Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156755/basic)'s and [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)'s comments on the question, I realized my error and tested actually sending the `401 Unauthorized` status code and low-and-behold, Safari was working with the user/pass in the URL.

I didn't notice the caching while I was developing the API because I was logged into the Drupal site the API is built on and Drupal only does the full page caching for anonymous users. Interestingly, even the Chrome app, [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-packa/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher), which acts like a separate application, sends your cookies from the main Chrome application. I didn't even realize that I was logged into the site when I sent requests with it.

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html

Are you requiring a valid-user? in a block like this.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "By Invitation Only"
# Optional line:
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
AuthGroupFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/groups
Require group GroupName
```

Can you post the relevant httpd.conf block?

Comment: I am not using Apache for handling the authentication, but PHP. If a request doesn't already include the credentials, the site responds with `401 Unauthorized`.